# Tomcat Unable to Detect file from class path

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, tomcat7, classpath

I was trying spring boot project and there I was trying to load hibernate  properties.

for that I had written class LocalHibConfig to load hibernate configuration

now my hibernate.properties file  is there in my demo project at

src/main/java/resources/hibernate.properties

now I have below issue since above path is same path where my application.properties also presents

now in my LocalHibConfig class 
1. I am forced to load this properties file by below piece of code

```
  protected Properties getProperties() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
File file= new File(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties").getURL().getPath());

log.debug(" ++++ File Exists"+file.exists());   // O/p is true here

        properties.load(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));

        return properties;
    }
```

because it is not being loaded automatically why? since application.properties is being picked up automatically then why not hibernate.properties ?

I don't want to keep hibernate related properties in my application.properties

Comment: Read Spring Boot documentation and `@PropertySource`(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html). You are not forced to load your properties like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do something like this:

Say in your `hibernate.properties`, you have:

```
hibernate.prop1=foo
hibernate.prop2=bar
```

You can get those properties like this:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties 
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hibernate")
public class HibernateConfig {
    private String prop1; // getter + setter should be defined (setter is more important)
    private String prop2; // getter + setter
}
```

Then you can inject your `HibernateConfig` where you want read those properties

Comment: This is the way to inject but why even I need to inject the properties when ideally it should be auto picked up by hibernate,  as per  various hibernate tutorials if configuration properties or xml kept on class path it picks it up automatically right? while in above ex. we are explicitly injecting it

Comment: No, nothing is picked up automatically, Spring boot pickes up automatically all `application-${profile}.properties` but all other properties files should be explicitly imported.